# How to delete auto start apps in BlackBerry?

Tags: java, blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Hello i had this bug in one of my apps. I can't uninstall it if its marked as an auto start app in Blackberry descriptor. When i turn off this option i can delete it.

Someone has experimented this kind of problem?

i have tried going to apps administrator but the option isn't showing there either.

**NOTE:** i installed this application through eclipse as DEV.

I found someone having the same problem as me here : https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Deleting-an-autostart-app/td-p/1436287

Comment: As that support forum entry suggests, marking an app for auto-start does not normally make it impossible to delete. There is something else going on.  Try a sample app, make sure your OSes are suitable (compile using a JRE less than your device) and test that.  Document your test completely here if it doesn't work, so we can replicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to force-delete an app, if you know the module name:

```
javaloader -usb erase -f example.cod
```

You can find the Javaloader executable inside the bin folder in your Blackberry SDK folder. For the eclipse plugin, you can also find it inside the component packs:

```
<eclipse folder>\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpackX.X.X_X.X.X.X\components\bin

(the X are the versions numbers, that might be different in your case).
```

You might also be able to do it from the device settings, inside the installed apps screen, if you change the view to list the modules.